# Error 415 while testing my wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf, fiddler

I have a Restful service that has this `OperationContract`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
  UriTemplate = "json")]
Response JSONData(Request request);
```

and is configured in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
          openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="01:01:00" openTimeout="01:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingXML"/>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingJSON"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="SearchService.SearchService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService" contract="SearchService.ISearchService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint
          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
          helpEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The request object is formed in this way

```
[DataContract]
public class Query
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string birthDate { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Input
{
    [DataMember]
    public Query query { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string login_username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string login_password { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public Input input { get; set; }
}
```

I created a small client to test this query and I've also tested it using `WCFTestClient` and works fine. If I try to access this through fiddler though I get a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error.

I tried this in the following manner

```
POST, http://localhost:8080/HostDevServer/SearchService.svc/json, HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 368

{ "input": { "login_password": "pass", "login_username": "login name", "query": { "birthDate": "", "name": "robert" } } }
```

I also tried deploying this service and see if fiddler would be able to access it then, but things got even more confusing because now instead of getting a `415` I was getting a `400` complaining about `'Reference to an object not set to an instance of the object.'` and the small command line client I created would complain about `There was no endpoint listening at` the location of my service.

My question is, is there something wrong with my configuration file, or did I compose the fiddler request in the wrong way? If yes how can I fix this so I can access my service normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you are using `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`

This means that you need to wrap the actual data with the name of the variable expected by your `OperationContract`. In short this should work

```
{ "response": { "input": { "login_password": "pass", "login_username": "login name", "query": { "birthDate": "", "name": "robert" } } } }
```

If you want to keep the body content as is then I suggest you use `Bare` instead of `Wrapped` for the body style.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the edit, sometimes my hands write stuff on their own.